# tc-server log4j logging configuration file is missing. Logging may cause faults

Tags: tomcat, logging, tomcat7, tcserver

I am using vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.0 on windows 7.
On my instance I get the following error on startup.

"log4j logging configuration file is missing. Logging may cause faults."

My wrapper log:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/24 10:40:09 | Sep 24, 2013 10:40:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/24 10:40:09 | INFO: Initialization processed in 851 ms
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/24 10:41:40 | [FATAL] log4j logging configuration file is missing. Logging may cause faults.
```

My application logs correctly and I assume this is related to loging at the server level.
Any idea where should I place the missing log4 file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:
The embedded tomcats (6.0.x and 7.0.x) in vfabric-tc-server-developer are provided with tomcats tomcat-juli-adapters.jar tomcat-juli.jar jars by default under:

```
%TCSERVER_HOME%\tomcat-7.0.X\bin\extras and %TCSERVER_HOME%\tomcat-7.0.X\bin
```

So your log4j configuration should go under your instance conf dir.
Then you should make sure you delete/rename the exiting logging.properties file.
Now you should not see the fault message above and you will start to see tomcat related logs.

I tested this under tc-server versions 2.7.0 and 2.9.2